# compare two arrays in dataweave2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave

i want code to compare two arrays and determine if they are equal or not irrespective of their order

[a,b,c] compared to [a, b,c ] should be true
[a,b,c] compare to [a,c,b] should be true as well.

i tried using the diff function from dataweave 2.0 but it works only if the parameters are Json objects not for arrays.

Comment: Is ordering an option?  You can order first then compare.

Comment: yes. that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @George mentioned a simple orderBy fixed my issue

```
import diff from dw::util::Diff
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{

  result: diff(payload.array orderBy  $, vars.array orderBy $).matches


}
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Diff module with the unordered property

```
import diff from dw::util::Diff
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  result: diff(payload.array, vars.array, {unordered: true}).matches
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work if you are comparing two arrays. it work if you are to compare two json objects with different orders. i did a test of that and it doesnt work.